# Understanding JavaScript Doc Notations

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to understand how to read javascript documentations. Why don't the square brackets close before the commas?

for example

```
d3.js: selection.style(name[, value[, priority]])

jQuery: $.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )
```

Comment: Because they refer to non required parameters, and if there is no parameter name, no need for the comma either.

Comment: okay, i know this is probably a very silly question so bear with me. Are you saying that if the brackets close e.g. if the input arguments were ([name]), then it means 'name' is a required parameter/argument but if its (name[,value]) then 'value' is optional but 'name' is required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Square brackets denote optional parts - just imagine drawing a strikethrough line from `[` to the nearest `]`. So in the jquery example you can omit `data` or `complete` or both:

> $.load( url <s>, data</s>  , complete ) - ok
>
> $.load( url , data <s>, complete</s> )  - ok
>
> $.load( url <s>, data, complete</s> )  - ok

In the d3 snippet, if you omit `value`, you also have to omit `priority`

> selection.style(name <s>, value, priority</s>) - ok
>
> selection.style(name, value <s>, priority</s>)  - ok
>
> selection.style(name <s>, value</s> , priority) - NOT ok